# Old question appeared in First Posts

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

[image: First Post Queue]

A [nearly month old question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/5649/is-it-possible-that-the-recipient-of-a-heart-transplant-would-display-some-of-th) just popped up in my first-posts queue, is there any reason why this would happen?  It went into the queue 56 minutes ago and was taken straight out when I voted on it as a mod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over time we've tweaked the exact criteria where posts go into different queues, I'm fairly sure this post was enqueued when we last tweaked the first posts queue.